# How can i test class, inspect.isclass() not working in my case?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to test if item[1] value is a class object without knowing type.  I have tried:

> inspect.isclass(item[1])

as suggested in previous posts with no luck.

> ```
> if isinstance(item[1], (type, dfvfs.path.tsk_path_spec.TSKPathSpec)):
> ```

is what i currently am using to test, but again, trying to test without knowing type.  How can I properly test?

Comment: Do you want this? `type(item[1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(item[1], dfvfs.path.tsk_path_spec.TSKPathSpec)
```

will, unsurprisingly, tell you whether `item[1]` is an instance of [class] `dfvfs.path.tsk_path_spec.TSKPathSpec`.

It's worth noting, however, that code like this usually points to a suboptimal design.  You may want to rethink the way you're accessing `item[1]`.